# Problem creating edges in network chart using Pyvis and Pandas

Tags: python, database, numpy, networkx, visualization

Iv'e been stuck for quite some time now and can't figure out wat is going wrong in this code...
I'm trying to create edges between column a 'mainartist' and column b 'artistrel' / column c 'artistlu.

The code works but only shows the nodes (with the intended edges) based on the information cell a2, b2, c2. Instead of connecting a2, b2:b52, c2:c52

```
from pyvis.network import Network
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

net = Network()

file_loc = "/Users/jamiekonincks/Documents/programmeren/Data/network_chart/art_templ1.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, usecols=["mainartist", "artistrel", "artistlu"])

df = df.dropna(subset=['mainartist', 'artistrel', 'artistlu'])

# Select the first cell of the mainartist column
mainartist = df.iloc[0]['mainartist']

# Add the first cell of the mainartist column as a node
net.add_node(mainartist, label=mainartist, color='#3da831', size=20)

# Iterate over the cells in the artistrel and artistlu columns
for artistrel, artistlu in zip(df['artistrel'], df['artistlu']):
    # Add artistrel and artistlu as nodes
    net.add_node(artistrel, label=artistrel, color='#9a31a8', size=20)
    net.add_node(artistlu, label=artistlu, color='#9a31a8', size=20)

    # Add edges between mainartist and artistrel, and mainartist and artistlu
    net.add_edge(mainartist, artistrel, width=2)
    net.add_edge(mainartist, artistlu, width=2)

# Enable the display of labels for nodes
net.toggle_physics(False)

# Increase the size of the network visualization
net.barnes_hut()
net.show_buttons(filter_=['physics'])

net.show('list_of_nodes_with_color.html')
```

How do I properly add edges between column a 'mainartist' (only information is cell 2) and column b 'artistrel' (b2:b52) / column c 'artistlu' (c2:c52)?

Thanks!

Comment: i think we need a sample of your df in order to reproduce the issue you're having. can you copy and paste the output from `df.head().to_dict()` in your question?

Comment: This partly answered my question already :)
Result of df.head().to_dict(): 
{'mainartist': {0: 'kiki', 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 'artistrel': {0: 'thisisagoodtime', 1: 'babytmgxx', 2: 'saxondavis', 3: 'seb_imotek_nodd', 4: 'saravalencia148'}, 'artistlu': {0: 'lisa.dana.celena', 1: 'noaah_dj', 2: '4josedavid', 3: 'soraa.music', 4: 'adamm_scarratt'}}

How do i prevent column 'mainartist' to give the nan error?

Comment: So I've found a way to prevent the 'nan' error by using: df = df.dropna(). However when using this all my nodes (without edges) disappear and instead the graph is now showing the node 'kiki' (from column 'mainartist'), sharing one edge with 'thisisagoodtime' (from column 'artistrel'), and the node 'lisa.dana.celena' (from column 'artistlu') without an edge to 'kiki' (from column 'mainartist').

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out after a long day of scouring the internet. I did it using another code however. If somebody has the same question in the future... This is how i got it done:

```
from pyvis.network import Network
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np


# Read in the data, skipping the first row (which contains the column names)
got_data = pd.read_excel("your_own_file_path_here.xlsx")
print(got_data)

# Create a Network object
got_net = Network(height="750px", width="75%", bgcolor="white", font_color="222222")

# Set the physics layout of the network
got_net.force_atlas_2based()

# Create a list of edges, with weights based on the number of occurrences of each artist name
edge_data = []
for index, row in got_data.iterrows():
    src = row['artistmain']
    src2 = row['artistrel']
    dst1 = row['artistrel']
    dst2 = row['artistlu']
    w1 = got_data['artistrel'].value_counts()[dst1]
    w2 = got_data['artistlu'].value_counts()[dst2]
    edge_data.append((src, dst1, w1))
    edge_data.append((src, dst2, w2))
    edge_data.append((src2, dst2, w2))

# Add the nodes and edges to the network
for e in edge_data:
    src = e[0]
    scr2 = e[1]
    dst = e[1]
    w = e[2]

    got_net.add_node(src, src, title= " Interactions: " + str(w))
    got_net.add_node(dst, dst, title=dst)
    got_net.add_edge(src, dst, value= int(w))

# Get the neighbor map
neighbor_map = got_net.get_adj_list()

# Add neighbor data to node hover data
for node in got_net.nodes:
    neighbors = neighbor_map[node["id"]]
    neighbors_with_numbering = ["{}. {}".format(i+1,neighbor) for i,neighbor in enumerate(neighbors)]
    node["title"] += " Neighbors: "+", ".join(neighbors_with_numbering)


got_net.show_buttons(filter_=('physics'))

# Display the network
got_net.show("artistrelations.html")
```